# Add submenu inside other submenu in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm coding in Google Apps Script, and I neet to make a second level submenu, but everytime I try to add the following code, I get the error from the 2nd image:

```js
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('WB_Tools')
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('LE Ready')
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Generate E-mail'))
        .addItem('SMR', 'WB_Tools.GENERATELESMRREADY')
        .addItem('Non SMR', 'WB_Tools.GENERATELENPIREADY')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Add to SMR/MR Pending tool', 'WB_Tools.ADDPENDINGACT')
      .addItem('Update SMR/MR Dashboard', 'WB_Tools.UPDATEDASHBOARD'))
    .addSeparator()
```

[image: error]

With that, I must show you the line 62 of the file:
[image: line 62]

So, what should I do to achieve the following:

Global menu

- First submenu

  - Second submenu

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Item 4

Comment: Opa! Eu acho que o ```addSeparator()``` que está causando o problema...o que está no final....It's recommended that you share more of your code, so we can get the whole picture - of course, without sensitive data.

Comment: hey @santosOnit, thanks for replying, but it wasn't the `addSeparator()`. What was happening was that I wasn't creating the child subMenu inside the parenthesis of the parent subMenu hahah. But thanks anyways!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('TestData')
              .addItem('testDataFixedHeaders(1)', 'testDataFixedHeaders')
              .addItem('testDataRandowHeaders(1)', 'testDataRandowHeaders')
              .addItem('testDataWrappedText','testDataWrpdStrings1')
              .addItem('testData1(2)', 'testData1')
              .addItem('testData2(2)', 'testData2')
              .addItem('testData3(2)', 'testData3')
              .addItem('testData4(2)', 'testData4')
              .addItem('testData5(3)', 'testData5')
              .addItem('testData6(3)', 'testData6')
              .addItem('testData7(3)', 'testData7')
              .addItem('testData8(3)', 'testData8')
              .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('sub sub')
              .addItem('new','elfunko')))
```

Comment: oh damn, that was it! I wasn't creating the items/submenus inside the parenthesis of the parent submenu hahaha! Thanks!